# Elixir: how to post on a rest API (redmine) with httpotion

Tags: json, rest, elixir, redmine

Hello I am trying to create and issue posting to Redmine API

```
def createIssue(issue) do
  value = %{"project_id" => 1, "subject" => "Example", "priority_id" => 1, "tracker_id" => 1}
  content = Poison.Encoder.encode(value, [])
  HTTPotion.post("#{url}/issues.json", [body: "issue=#{content}" , basic_auth: auth()])
end
```

The result of the code above is the following

```
Started POST "/issues.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-26 11:47:25 +0200
Processing by IssuesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"issue"=>"{\"tracker_id\":1,\"subject\":\"Example\",\"project_id\":1,\"priority_id\":1}"}
Current user: admin (id=1)
```

The right response from redmine should be as far as I can understand the following

```
Parameters: {"issue"=>{"tracker_id":1,"subject": "Example","project_id":1,"priority_id":1}}
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: Have you called this API from another language before? If yes, what code did you use?

Comment: Try adding `plug` as a dependency in your `mix.exs` if you don't have already, and try this code out: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e532956e00c9630b823fe4434cbe9dec I'll post the explanation as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you Dogbert. I was trying to do something similar via quote/unquote. Your gist did work! I will credit you in my github repository and mark your explanation as answer when you post it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not HTTPotion. You are not encoding the "issue" node as JSON.

```
def createIssue(issue) do
  content = Poison.encode!(%{"issue" => %{"project_id" => 1, "subject" => "Example", "priority_id" => 1, "tracker_id" => 1}})
  HTTPotion.post("#{url}/issues.json", [body: content, basic_auth: auth()])
end
```

Comment: If this works, I find it strange that `"issue=#{json}"` was decoding to `{"issue": json}`. It should have thrown an error or something if it expects the whole body to be valid JSON.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Hi Simone, thanks for your help. With the code you suggested I get the following response by Redmine: `Processing by IssuesController#create as JSON Parameters: {"{\"issue\":{\"tracker_id\":1,\"subject\":\"Example\",\"project_id\":1,\"priori‌​ty_id\":1}}"=>nil} Current user: admin (id=1) Rendered common/error_messages.api.rsb (1.0ms) Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 221ms (Views: 60.8ms | ActiveRecord: 141.7ms) `